# I need to get the name of facebook user who isnt a friend but has authorised the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a comment interface that needs to show peoples Facebook profile pics and names. When I try to get the info using /me in the graph API it works. But if I use someone else's userID I get an error:

```
"message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "EY/oRYYby2u"
```

It works if I am friends with the other person, so is not being friends why this doesn't work? They have both authorized the app. Do I need to server side store everyone's access tokens and use the corresponding token to access the data I need?

Comment: Yes you need the access token to get the current user friends, if of course he has allowed your app and you got the token then (at least this is what I remember).

Comment: I don't want to get the current user friends. I have an access token for each person, and it works for the individual. But when I try to get the name of someone who is not a friend I get an error even tho that person has authorised the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the app token you can get name of each user connected to app.

https://graph.facebook.com/userID?access_token=App_token

Comment: I'm using a user token, not an app token. (which from here seems like the right thing to be doing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens). My problem is that I need to be able to get the name of a given Facebook ID for another user who is not friends with the current user (who I have the access token for) but has authorised the app.